# set cookie in php directly from form input

Tags: php, html, cookies

The code below is a simple experiment.Here i am trying to create a name input form which will be set as a cookie in the browser.But it appears that it is not working at all.Where might be the problem here.I am a beginner in php.So,it would be great if someone point out the mistakes i have made

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name'])){
$cookie_value=$_POST['name'];
setcookie('user',$cookie_value, time() + 3600, '/');
}
?>
<html>
<body>

<?php
if(isset($cookie_value)&& !empty($cookie_value)) {
    echo "user is".$cookie_value;
} else {
    echo "Cookies are not set";
}
?>
<form action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?> method='post'>
<input type='text' name='text'>
<input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` which will firstly tell you of an Undefined index... etc.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: who is giving all the sudden downvotes ?? :<

Comment: I'm pretty sure that little emo kid downvoted everyone after he deleted his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `$_POST['name']` but your inputs name is `text`. May want to change the variable to `$_POST['text']`.

Comment: thanks!! browser didn't warn me for this.how can i get an error message for this types of error??

Comment: You can get common php errors by adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the beginning of the file.

Comment: *"how can i get an error message for this types of error??"* @al-Zami Are you not reading the comments under your question? Posted nearly 5 mins. before this comment? and 4 mins. after your initial question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i put your error handling code at the front of my first php tag.Didn't work when i changed the input name attribute

Comment: @al-Zami If you changed the input name attribute, you won't be getting an Undefined index for it now, will we? ;-)

Comment: i've set an invalid name inside $_POST[] .didn't work either !!

Answer (score 0):

After setting cookie and redirecting to another page (cookie will be visible after first redirect) you can access that cookie using `$_COOKIE['user']`.

I can't see that in your code and I'm pretty sure that's the reason.

And next problem is wrong input name, just like @castis pointed out.

Comment: He never redirects though, he's just setting `$cookie_value` which is immediately available.

Comment: @castis: yep, but I was talking about value from cookie ;)